# I got error "TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'gnupghome'" once trying to use Python encryption with GnuPG

Tags: python, gnupg, python-gnupgp

I am using the Python gnupg to encrypt/decrypt a file, but I got stuck in error message as my question title. I also check folder ~/.gnupg already exist as I have done installed the python-gnupg.

```
import gnupg
gpg    = gnupg.GPG(gnupghome='/home/user/.gnupg')
gpg.encoding    = 'utf-8'
.
.
.
```

Actually code is running in local machine, but on server isn't working. I think that the problem come up with the server configuration with GNUPG or wrong installation.
Can you please help me out if you are used to face this issue!

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  Which version of the python gnupg module do you have?

Comment: The docs and [the source code](https://github.com/vsajip/python-gnupg/blob/master/gnupg.py#L876) both indicate that's the correct call. The error you're getting isn't a problem with paths or anything, it's because whatever `gnupg.GPG` is, it's not actually the `GPG` class from `gnupg`. It's possible somebody dumped a corrupted (or maybe very old?) version of `gnupg.py` on your server, but you're going to have to go take a look at the server to figure it out; all anyone can tell you based on that error message is that whatever `gnupg.GPG` is, it doesn't accept `gnupghome` as a keyword arg.

Comment: Huh, and apparently there's a duplicate; looks like I was right and there are version discrepancies, where some versions used a different keyword name. Man that's terrible practice. I guess it's still pre-version 1.0, so they're allowed to break things on new releases, but that just seems gratuitous.

Comment: @ewong I am using python-gnupg verion 0.4.8

Comment: @ShadowRanger, I'm really confusing now, but I notice that my testing server working, in ~/home/user/.gnupg has file gpg.conf, but the not working server has no gpg.conf file. I have no idea on this, and I don't know is it that problem I faced because of no this file or not.

Comment: Hi guys! thank you so much for your answers. Finally I can fixed my own issue; I found the reason why always got above error message. Because of in my project venv has two packages 1. gnupg, 2. python-gnupg. Just remove/uninstall gnupg and keep python-gnupg then it works fine!.